# iframe and image container code improvements MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

As a part of my first project i had to implement image and video display in views using MVC 5. It is working and i'm quite happy with the achievement, however there are some improvements had to be made, how would you recommend to improve following code:

to display a picture i used this code:

```
<div style="float: none; margin: auto auto 30px auto  ;height: 280px; width: 400px; ">
    <div id="imageContainer">
        <img src="~/Images/@Html.Raw(Model.ImagePath)"  />
    </div>
</div>
```

in a case when i don't provide a path, this container stays empty but still visible as empty block on the page with image icon, indicating that image suppose to be here... How i can get rid of it, if i dont want picture to be shown in this view?

The same situation with video container, i simply using embeded youtube link as a `Videolink` for video:

```
 <iframe src=@Html.Raw(Model.VideoLink) width="560" height="315" frameborder="1" align="middle" display:block style="margin:auto auto 30px auto"></iframe>
```

If i provide `Videolink` - it works fine, if i dont, i have a container showing an error. Is there a way to simply hide those containers if there are no input made?

i'll show you the way i set it all up, it all in one class `Media`

```
 public class Media
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string title { get; set; }
        [Required, StringLength(512)]
        public string description { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [AllowHtml]
        public string body { get; set; }
        public string ImagePath { get; set; }
        public string VideoLink { get; set; }
        public string Source { get; set; }
        public TagsEnum TagsEnum { get; set; }
        [Column(TypeName = "datetime2")]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd MMMM , yyyy HH:mm}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime? NewsDate { get; set; }

    }
```

**Update**

this is what i think it should look like using Sam's advise, right? If so, it is still not giving right result

```
@if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(b.ImagePath)) 
    { 

    }
    else
    { 
            <div style="float: right; margin: 10px 10px 25px 25px; height: 100px; width:150px">
                <div id="imageContainer">           
                     <img src="~/Images/@Html.Raw(b.ImagePath))" style='height: 100%; width: 100%;' />
                   </div>
            </div>
    }
```

Comment: `@if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(model.property))`

Comment: looks promising, thanks! but were does it goes to, View? Controller? I'm a beginner in ASP.Net

Comment: it's prefixed with an `@`.  That makes it Razor syntax.

Comment: it helped, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(b.ImagePath)) { 
    @<div style="float: right; margin: 10px 10px 25px 25px; height: 100px; width:150px">
        <div id="imageContainer">           
             <img src="~/Images/@Html.Raw(b.ImagePath))" style='height: 100%; width: 100%;' />
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Yes, this way it works like a charm. Appreciate your help.